# Open up Mac firewall to allow inbound traffic to see a website in development on port 8000

Tags: macos

I’m looking to remotely share a web page that I’m working on with a client. I’m using foundation framework which has a CLI which creates a server and IP address that the test website runs on. http://192.168.1.3:8000/ I want my clients to see it using that port on my Mac remotely.

I’ve tried to open that port number via

```
sudo pico /etc/pf.conf 

# Open port 1234 for TCP on all interfaces
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8000
```

But the other person still can’t see it.

First of all is this dangerous to open up that port up for TCP traffic? I'm thinking yes... I know I can lock it down to an IP address range but because they are just using a standard internet connection won’t their IP be dynamic and likely to change…?

Is there a better way? Can I use port forwarding?

Essentially I am trying to open up the Mac firewall to allow inbound traffic from my clients to that ip address via that port number from one of their devices like a mobile, tablet or laptop. That isn't local on my network.

Comment: 192.168.1.3 is an internal IP only reachable from within your network. You would also need a port-forwarding from your router to your machine, and then the clients would have to connect to the external IP of your router to see your website.

Comment: Which could open me up to all kinds of hacking, spoofing etc... Would a better version to have it over SSH?

Comment: You should port-forward only port 8000, limiting the danger a bit. If you cannot limit the firewall to your client's ip-addresses, think about setting up at least password protection for your website so not everybody else is able to see it. In the end, if you want to host the site on your machine (even just during developing), you have to accept that their is some risk in doing so as your machine essentially becomes a web server.